# A custom method for events

Tags: c++, events

Basically what I am trying to do here is to create an event system for a simple game engine I am working on.

I'm trying to make this program as platform independent as possible with the C++ language so I am ruling out threading for the moment.

The basic idea that is that:

```
//outside game loop (initialization)
o_check_for_events(O_CHECK_ALL_EVENTS); // this should add the events to some sort of list

// inside game loop
event = o_get_next_event(); // return the next event in the queue
// .. 
// do stuff with events
```

That would be a sample game event loop. What I want out of this though is an option that I can ask the system to wait for an event (easier of the two) and/or be able to check for events even while the game is running.

What I want to know is if it is more efficient to have methods that interrupt the flow for a short period of time, or else a threaded program that checks for events simultaneously (assume that the thread functions are safe)?

Comment: Why do your functions start with `o_`? Also, C++ has platform-independent threading facilities, which you will find in `<thread>` header. Also, what do you mean by "more efficient?"

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the `o_` is just a naming convention in the project.

Comment: Then it's a bad convention. A namespace should be used instead. What about my other points?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with the convention. and by more efficient I mean which will be able to deliver messages quicker while also using as little resources as possible i.e. processing power and memory

Comment: Have you profiled the current method to see if it's really a hotpath in the execution? The problem with the convention is that it introduces unnecessary noise and doesn't really help with name clashes; both of those problems can be easily solved with a namespace. Have you taken a look at C++'s threading/async model?

Comment: I am yet to fully profile them, its just a case of finishing the method completely to comply with the engine. I see where you are coming from as regards the namespace and I agree now that I think about it, thanks. I have not looked at the threading/async model as of yet since I'm not on my development computer at the moment. Thanks a lot for the help also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple questions here, but your question of whether or not it is more efficient to have threaded asynchronous event handling or blocking message handling is likely going to lean in the direction of asynchronous handling. Unless you are encountering some very extreme locality of reference issues, which would honestly likely be encountered regardless of threaded or not. I would recommend you do not implement an asynchronous callback system, as your engine is likely going to see far better improvements from threading other intensive operations. Callback systems are extremely low overhead.

To answer more your architectural question, I will explain a simple architecture I have seen in modern AAA game engines, and something I have written myself. Typically, the game engine framework will have an entire system dedicated to handling events, and this is often built on top of a generic messaging, or callback system. Events are triggered at specific points throughout the program flow, and are typically delivered immediately by the corresponding event/callback (unless you support time delay events). At that point, any entity, or system that implements a callback listening interface, and is subscribed to that event will receive the notification and potential payload.

As a final note, your method names == scary. :)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I think I can come up with something using what you just said. Also its just a naming convention, that methods to do with the engine named `Orpheus` (not my idea) begin with `o_` then the rest is also seperated by `_` e.g. `do_something()`

Comment: Instead of starting with an o, the methods should all be inside the namespace Orpheus. (That is if you want to conform to normality and not irritate to hell any outsider/new project member looking at the code)